# How to detect relation change in Ember.js after createRecord

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have

```
Ember.computed("task.inputValues.[]", ..
```

Inside this method at certain condition, i trigger creation of new inputValues that have a task set with *belongsTo*. But after records and relations are successfully set in Ember database (using "*createRecord*"), "*task.inputValues.[]*" does not catch/trigger computed method to recalculate?

Comment: Not directly related, but generally folks recommend avoiding computed properties with side effects (such as creating new records). The reason being you can end up getting errors in strange places if your component gets destroyed while you are working with the Ember store. Have you looked into using ember-concurrency tasks to handle your needs here? It might simplify other things (or help you avoid concurrency issues that would crop up in the future ...)

Comment: From component i am sending signal to Controller which is calling createRecord upon store. Then if it would get recomputed singnal would not be sent again. (when i force recompute by another action, everything will get drawn as it should, but at start i haveto check if some entities exist and if not then i have to create them at that point and force redraw)

Answer (score 0):

As Acorncom mentioned "*folks recommend avoiding computed properties with side effects (such as creating new records)*"

Seems there is some kind of protection in Ember that prohibits recursive triggering of computed property by itself.

The solution was to move records creating code from computed property to Observer, after new records got inserted by the observer, computed property selector "task.inputValues.[]" did trigger.